# How to convert a text file into ARFF format?

Tags: weka

I'm using WEKA tool for text classification, and I have to convert plain text files into ARFF format. However, I don't know how to do that. Can anyone please help me to convert a text file into ARFF format?

---

Thank you Renklauf for ur response,

I didn't understood these points "Since text editors like Notepad only allow a limited number of columns, you'll need to get something like Notepad++ to fit everything on one line." .. can u plz explain in brief ..

Suppose the text data is like a simple sport article  like

" Basketball is a team sport, the objective being to shoot a ball through a basket horizontally positioned to score points while following a set of rules. Usually, two teams of five players play on a marked rectangular court with a basket at each width end. Basketball is one of the world's most popular and widely viewed sports" ...

This is my text document and I want to convert this to arff format .. and after that I need to use that arff format file for SVM text classification ..

Comment: What's the format of your txt file? Did you try [CSVLoader](http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc/weka/core/converters/CSVLoader.html)?

Comment: @Mahesh: Each article must be on a single line and enclosed in quotes. Your quoted article is 4 lines long. All 4 lines need to be placed on a SINGLE line and enclosed in quotes.  Depending on the length of the article you may run out of columns if you use a text editor like Notepad.  This is why I recommend you use Notepad++ which allows you to have lines of unlimited length (using the Join Lines function).

Answer (score 2):

For a document classification task, each document is considered an attribute and must be enclosed in quotes.   Suppose you have a corpus of 10 sports articles tagged as either pro-Yankees or pro-Red Sox for a classifier that automatically classifies sports articles as either pro-Yankees or pro-Red Sox.  You need to take each document, enclose it in quotes,*place it on a single line*, and then place your {yankees, red_sox} attribute value after the quotes-enclosed string.

```
 @relation yankeesOrRedSox
 @attribute article string
 @attribute yankeesOrSox { yankees, red_sox }
 @data

 "text of article 1 here", yankees
 .
 .
 .
 "text of article 10 here", red_sox
```

It's key that the article is placed on a single line. When I began using Weka for text classification, this is a point that caused me a lot of frustration at first.  Since text editors like Notepad only allow a limited number of columns, you'll need to get something like Notepad++ to fit everything on one line.  Notepad++ has a Join Lines function that allows you to place a lot of text on a single line.

Hope this helps.

Comment: No .. In the case of the data format of arff it ll work ... Actually that is a plain text i.e., article on sports and i need to convert that plain text into arff format ... tnx for ur response ...

Comment: But, this kind of format is not supporting by weka classifier (SMO algorithm used for classification) ... It is giving an error like SMO can't handle with String data ... what should I do ??? Is there any better option for text classification using SVM(Support vector machine)??

Comment: @Mahesh  Did you use the StringToWordVector filter to convert each article into a vector of words?  I just tried it out using SMO and it works fine.

Comment: ya ... I tried with that one also .. But this time weka is not allowing to classify with SMO (i.e., In classification SMO is not highlighted to select) .... I don't know why ???

Comment: What if the txt file has 10,000,000 records?