# Class attribute in ARFF file

Tags: java, attributes, classification, weka

how is it possible to add a class attribute in a WEKA ARFF file by using Java?

In particular, my ARFF structure (according to what is stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9192318/how-to-convert-a-text-file-into-arff-format)) should be:

```
@attribute text string
@attribute classifyIn {basketball,nonbasketball}
```

My question is: how to declare `classifyIn` programmatically?

**My procedure:**

I declared the ARFF attributes as follows:

```
FastVector attributes = new FastVector(2);

attributes.addElement(new Attribute("text", (FastVector) null));    

FastVector classes = new FastVector();
classes.addElement(className);
classes.addElement("non" + className);
attributes.addElement(new Attribute("class",classes));
```

and I am inserting entries as follows:

```
double[] newInst = new double[2];
newInst[0] = (double)data.attribute(0).addStringValue(textValue);
newInst[1] = (double)data.attribute(1).addStringValue(className);
```

where `className` is either the string `basketball` or the string `nonbasketball`.

**The error:**

However, when I run the code, the following error appears:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22252449/add-class-attribute-in-arff-file) is a related question, which did not receive an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code has to be modified in the following way:

```
newInst[1] = (double)data.attribute(1).indexOfValue(className);
```